# Is it possible to execute snowflake python code (snowpark.Session) through airflow's SnowflakeOperator?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

I have an airflow DAG using SnowflakeOperator with sql="myscript.sql"

I'd like to have another member of this dag using snowflake.Session code, i.e. dataframe code.

Is there an easy way to set this up?

I've read the docs for [SnowflakeOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/stable/operators/snowflake.html) and I see there's a sql= parameter but it's unclear from the docs how well this works with the rest of the snowflake ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd need to use a PythonOperator and define a python_callable that uses the snowflake.Session code.

Here is a rough example. Link to latest [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html).

```
def snowflake_python_code(**airflow_context):
    # write custom code

dag = DAG()

task = PythonOperator(dag=dag, task_id='snowflake_python_task', python_callable=snowflake_python_code)
```